# InlineShapes disappear when the layout of a chart in Word is changed. Where do they go?

Tags: c#, charts, ms-word, ms-office, vsto

I've been developing a Word-AddIn (Office 365 version 1706, Windows 10) which basically stores data in charts so they could be fed updated data from our servelets and ultimately the chart updates itself with all the data it needs.

This works perfectly fine **EXCEPT** when I alter the layout options for a chart from the default *"In Line with Text"* to *"With Text Wrapping"* to have multiple charts next to each other for example.

How this works, as long as you don't alter the layout options, is by accessing the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application COM object, which has a Selection object, which furthermore has InlineShapes, is like so:

```
var inlineShapes = Application.Selection.InlineShapes;
if(inlineShapes > 0)
{
    for(var i = 1; i < inlineShapes.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        if (inlShape.HasChart == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
            return new WordChart(inlShape);
    }
}
```

For sake of simplicity I spared you the whole ordeal of dealing with COM objects.
Again, this works if you don't tamper with the layout options of the chart, but as soon as the layout has been altered to say *"Behind Text"* I can't find that chart in any InlineShape.

Has anyone experienced this before?
I've combed through the `Application.Selection` object and couldn't find anything.
However the InlineShape is still in the Application.InlineShapes object itself, but how would I know which one is to be selected?

I would really appreciate ANY input, because as of now I have no idea on what to do anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found those little charts!

This Stackoverflow post helped me:
[How to check which shapes/objects are selected/active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221728/how-to-check-which-shapes-objects-are-selected-active)

More details to what solved my problem:

Once I changed the the layout options (see original question) I wouldn't be able to find Charts as InlineShapes anymore.
Instead they would be listed under `Selection.ShapeRange.get_Item(i)` (I checked for Shapes/InlineShapes, so I didn't see items as what a chart could be).

Now you could either convert them to InlineShapes, which does exactly that, in Word as well, which you don't want, or convert that Shape to your `VSTO.WordChart`, which I did.